# How can i sort dataTable based on tag value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js

i wanted to sort my `dataTable` based on `aria-` **tag**.

here is what i'm trying

1. **[for all first `td`]** all `aria-class="folder"` to be listed first in **ascending order**, then `aria-class="file"`
2. **[for all 2nd `td`]** all values to be ordered in **descending order**

here is my **dataTable**

```js
$('#dttest').DataTable();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<h1>Example of broken datatables date sorting</h1>
<table id="dttest">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="Alice" aria-class="folder">
                Alice
            </td>
            <td aria-value="200">200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="AAram" aria-class="file">
                AAram
            </td>
            <td aria-value="900">900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="Charlie" aria-class="file">Charlie</td>
            <td aria-value="1200">1200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="charlee" aria-class="folder">charlee</td>
            <td aria-value="100">100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="kevin" aria-class="file">kevin</td>
            <td aria-value="2000">2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="abraham" aria-class="folder">abraham</td>
            <td aria-value="3000000">3000000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="martin" aria-class="file">martin</td>
            <td aria-value="5.9">5.9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Please help me thanks in advance!!!

Comment: https://codepen.io/gaurav_suman/pen/jqaaPK

Comment: Do yo want to use aria-* or you can create any data-*?

Comment: @BhumiShah, any of them is ok if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is use `data-order` and You can sort only one field at a time

Demo: https://codepen.io/creativedev/pen/LrpeOj

```
<script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<h1>Example of broken datatables date sorting</h1>
<table id="dttest">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>DoB</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="Alice" data-order="folder">
                Alice
            </td>
            <td aria-value="200">200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="AAram" data-order="file">
                AAram
            </td>
            <td aria-value="900">900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="Charlie" data-order="file">Charlie</td>
            <td aria-value="1200">1200</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="charlee" data-order="folder">charlee</td>
            <td aria-value="100">100</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="kevin" data-order="file">kevin</td>
            <td aria-value="2000">2000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="abraham" data-order="folder">abraham</td>
            <td aria-value="3000000">3000000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td aria-name="martin" data-order="file">martin</td>
            <td aria-value="5.9">5.9</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script>
$('#dttest').dataTable({
    "aaSorting": [[ 0, "desc" ]],
});
 </script>
```

Comment: yes it works perfectly, but on click of **ascending** and **descending** `icon` it is mixing `file` with `folder`. cannot we keep them seperately and `sort` them?

Comment: When you click on icon, it will asc, desc based on data-order only